# How to set the useragent in cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to fake the useragent in this cURL request. Is it possible?

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$useragent="Your UserAgent string goes here";
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $useragent,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before, but it did not work earlier, now it works fine!